# SQL Server Reporting Service URL asking for credentials but not responding after that

Tags: service, reporting-services, reporting, credentials

SQL Server Reporting Service URL asking for credentials but not responding after that.

It is asking for credentials for exactly 3 times even if I am entering correct password all the time and than after it does not ask and even not showing anything on the browser page. Both the below URLs are behaving same. My report services and server has been configured on port 80.

> http://ssphdev.xxx.com/Reports
>
> http://ssphdev.xxx.com/ReportServer

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any suggestions will be helpful. I have reports to retrieve from the server. And also want to test further on the same server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem...

- I changed URL to hostname to localhost and it worked

I guess the problem was that I have two virtual with the same name (obviously only one is ON at a time) and connected with same domain. I think somehow when I use hostname on URL it is trying to connect another dev machine which is off. And localhost worked.

This is my guess! If you are having such issues please try 'localhost' and see it solves..!!

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If keeps prompting for credentials even after setting as below
 authentication mode="Windows"
 identity impersonate="True"

Replace below code from "Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.xxxxxxx\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config 
        
            
            
        
with

Just remove RSWindowsNegotiate tag from the tag AuthenticationTypes