# SQL Server ReportServer Service keeps asking for credentials in browser

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using MS SQL 2018R2 Report Server Service the following URL's keep prompting for credentials:

```
http://ServerName/Reports
http://ServerName/Reportserver
```

Even after multiple attempts to enter user and password it still keeps asking for credentials, showing no index page for the reports. I am sure the credentials are correct. Only by using the browser the problem appears. It is not browser specific however.

It used to function for years, but all of a sudden it stopped working. We have not made any changes to RS configuration whatsoever. The problem is it won't connect and display the Reports page. Connection to the datasource is configured within the reports, but that's not the problem, we cannott even get to select a report to use. Desired behavior is a user would enter credentials once and then the index page with reports will show.

ReportBuilder3.0 or BIDS can easily render reports with same credentials. Also, SQL server agent runs several jobs executing SSIS packages which trigger reportingservices and they still run fine. Because these run fine I am hesitant to change settings like Service Account.

ReportService is used as a intranet reporting solution within our own domain. Configured at port 80.

I have read the following posts, but keep struggling for solution:

[Similar question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468767/sql-server-reporting-service-url-asking-for-credentials-but-not-responding-after)

[Old solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lukaszp/2008/03/27/solving-the-reporting-services-login-issue-in-the-february-ctp-of-sql-server-2008/)[2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lukaszp/2008/03/27/solving-the-reporting-services-login-issue-in-the-february-ctp-of-sql-server-2008/)

[Similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890873/sql-ssrs-report-manager-site-asking-to-login-every-time)

[Link 4](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9ef2f893-648b-46d3-9339-9fd06075570a/ssrs-prompting-for-usernamepassword-when-trying-to-access-the-report-installed-on-a-server-from?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Other sources:

[Report Service Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-2017)

[Service Account settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189964.aspx)

Comment: AD or cert changes recently?

Comment: We experienced some problems with AD creating new users recently, perhaps to solve this some settings have been changed, will look into it, thanks for bringing up the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Change the authentication mode in rsreportserver.config to Custom

```
<Authentication>
   <AuthenticationTypes>
     <Custom/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
   <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
  </Authentication>
```

2)Change the Authentication mode in web.config file in ReportServer to None. Also change the Impersonation to false.

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

3)Add Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.dll to bin folder in ReportServer.

4)Add Extensions in rsreportserver.config
Add the additional extension in Security Tag

```
<Security>
    <Extension Name="None" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.Authorization, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity" />
</Security>
```

Add the additional extension in Authentication Tag

```
<Authentication>
    <Extension Name="None" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.AuthenticationExtension, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity" />
</Authentication>
```

5)Add the following codegroup to configure the code access security in rssrvpolicy.config

```
<CodeGroup
class="UnionCodeGroup"
version="1"
PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
Name="Private_assembly"
Description="This code group grants custom code full trust. ">
<IMembershipCondition
class="UrlMembershipCondition"
version="1"
Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.dll"
/>
</CodeGroup>
```

6)Restart the reporting services, Anonymous Access should work.

You can find all these config files at - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer depending on the version you have installed for reporting services.

Comment: Where can I find Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.dll to apply to SSRS 2017?

Comment: does this also work in power bi report server?